# PHPExcel for laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpexcel, implements

I want to use my PHPExcel Laravel application. I installed the library in the vendor directory. What is the method to call my controller and thereby implement this example: http://g-ernaelsten.developpez.com/tutoriels/excel2007/?page=fondements#L2.1
In the posts I read it just had to write to the header

`use PHPExcel;`
`use PHPExcel_IOFactory;`

It's not sufficient

Who can help me start with this library? and integrate it into my project Laravel. Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maatwebsite made a built a Laravel package for PHPExcel. You can find it here https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel together with the documentation for it.

If for any reasons you prefer to not use this, you need to

```
include '/vendor/PHPExcel/PHPExcel';
include '/vendor/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php';
```

Comment: Good idea ! But I prefried PHPExcel use the library because the examples are numerous and well detailed

Comment: It's the same library, it's just put together for easier use with Laravel.

Comment: If you are bent on using it without the wrapper for Laravel, you need to use include 'PHPExcel.php'; 
include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php'; (prefixed with the actual path to your vendor folder)